# Using <li> and html id's with .each

Tags: jquery

I have a list of single word links and want to collapse various paragraphs on click.  Can someone help me understand why this code doesn't work?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#origins").click(function(){
            $("li").each(function(){
                $("#"+$(this).text()+"Content").animate({height:'0', opacity:'0'}, 500);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**  Added relevant HTML

```
<body>
    <h1 class='title'>Electronic Music: London</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a id='Origins'  href="#">Origins</a></li>
        <li><a id='Arrival'  href="#">Arrival</a></li>
        <li><a id='Clubs'    href="#">Clubs</a></li>
        <li><a id='Labels'   href="#">Labels</a></li>
        <li><a id='Examples' href="#">Examples</a></li>
        <li><a id='Credits' href="#">Credits</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p id='welcome' style='text-align:center;'>
        <br>
        Welcome!  Please click on any of the topics above to learn more.
    </p>

    <p id='originsContent'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your html code ?

Comment: What means <<doesn't work>>?

Comment: Please provide your "HTML"

Comment: Notice the difference: `id=Origins` and `$('#origins')`. And `$(this)` points to the object gotten in the `.each`, not the `$('#Origins')`

Comment: Also notice `id=originsContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $("#"+$(this).text().toLowerCase()+"Content").animate({height:'0', opacity:'0'}, 500);
    });
});
```

I add the toLowerCase() method to transform, for example, `Origins` to `origins` and I change a little bit the structure of your code.

Comment: Works!  Thanks for the reminder on that useful function.

Comment: If my answer could help you, you can validate it please :)

Comment: Why not `this.id.toLowerCase()`, since the `id` and the text are the same, and the approach using the `id` avoids calling jQuery (albeit this would be only a micro-optimisation, at best). Also it reduces the chance for problems being introduced from leading, or trailing, white-space.

Comment: It's terrible practice to just use `toLowerCase` to fix capitalization inconsistencies in your code. Avoid it and name all elements correctly

Comment: toLowerCase is being used as the text is being pulled from a list displayed on the site.  It must be upper case for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This will bring them back as well. Instead of just hiding them. Also you can replace slideUp animation with just regular animate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
         var text = $(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase();
         var para = $('#'+ text +'Content');
         if(para.is(':visible')){
             para.slideUp(500);
         }else{
             para.slideDown(500);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note the use of a fade and slide at the same time, hence my use of animate instead of slide.  Also, slide moves the top of the element a bit which is undesirable in this case.

Comment: @ogama8 yeah I just put it in there as filler.  The question focused more on targeting paragraph elements from a click. Not the style of animation. Just wanted to give you an alternative to just hiding, but also showing. You can just tack animation in place of slide animation.

Comment: ah, of course.  Cheers!